# How can I know the number of units consumed by each A.C. in a home

Tags: power-consumption

The question is fairly simple. I have three air conditioners in my home and the bill for their electricity consumption comes combined as only a single meter is installed. My question is Is there any other way possible to calculate the amount of electricity consumed by every A.C. separately without installing any new meters?

Comment: Get wall outlet power meters for each one.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You will need to use a watthour meter on each one to capture its cumulative use over time. Even if you know each unit’s draw when on, you won’t know what percentage of the time the unit is operating.